# How Can I Resize Tabview Images ? (iOS14)

Tags: swiftui, ios14

After I installed the iOS 14 tab view icon size are changed it is so ugly now. How can I reduce the size of images? I tried .font(.system(size:15)) but not affected.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzYge.png)

```
TabView(selection: self.$authVM.selectedTab) {
                                HomeTab()
                                    .tabItem {
                                        Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                                            .renderingMode(.template)
                                            .font(.system(size: 15))
                                        Text("Home")
                                }.tag(SelectedTab.home)
                                SwapsTab()
                                    .tabItem {
                                        Image(systemName: "hand.draw.fill")
                                            .renderingMode(.template)
                                            .font(.system(size: 15))
                                        Text("Swaps")
                                }.tag(SelectedTab.swaps)
                                DiscoverTab()
                                    .tabItem {
                                        Image(systemName: "gamecontroller.fill")
                                            .renderingMode(.template)
                                            .font(.system(size: 15))
                                        Text("Discover")
                                }.tag(SelectedTab.discover)
                                NotificationsTab()
                                    .tabItem {
                                        Image(systemName: "bell.fill")
                                            .renderingMode(.template)
                                            .font(.system(size: 15))
                                        Text("Notifications")
                                }.tag(SelectedTab.notifications)
                                MessagesTab()
                                    .tabItem {
                                        Image(systemName: "envelope.fill")
                                            .renderingMode(.template)
                                            .font(.system(size: 15))
                                        Text("Messages")
                                }.tag(SelectedTab.messages)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61728579/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi thanks but it's not a good idea to write a custom tab view only for a image size. The font size change trick is not working on iOS 14, I tried.